# Prove that in $S_n$ there are an equal number of even and odd permutations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Prove that in $S_n$ there are an equal number of even and odd permutations.

$S_n$ is a group of all possible permutations on a set of $n$ elements.   For this problem we can assume $n>1$.

I'm pretty sure I need to prove this by contradiction and show that if the numbers weren't even then $S_n$ wouldn't be a group, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: "we can assume" no! We _must_ assume, or else it is false.

Comment: the easiest way to see it is that for every odd permutation P, then P*P gives an even permutation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The map $\sigma \mapsto (12)\sigma$ is a bijection and it maps even permutations to odd ones and vice-versa.

Answer (score 9):

The map $\sigma \mapsto \hbox{sign}(\sigma)$ is a surjective homomorphism $S_n \to C_2$ whose kernel is the set of even permutations.

Answer (score 0):

To prove it you will need to show that the determinant of the n×n matrix with all entries equal to one is zero, which is very obvious. This is true from the explicit formulae of determinant of square matrices.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, you have just written an incorrect answer to a nine year old question that already has two good answers. If you want to help here, work on new questions.